# Android: How to know whether the notification panel is already open programmatically?

Tags: android, notifications, status

I wanted to know whether there is any way of knowing whether the notifications bar is open. I have the below code to open the notification bar from a program:

```
Object sbservice = getSystemService( "statusbar" );
Class<?> statusbarManager = Class.forName( "android.app.StatusBarManager" );
Method showsb;
if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= 17) {
    showsb = statusbarManager.getMethod("expandNotificationsPanel");
}
else {
    showsb = statusbarManager.getMethod("expand");
}
showsb.invoke( sbservice );
```

Is there any way to know whether the panel is already open?

Comment: Check this for a working solution: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53509108/how-to-detect-when-the-notification-system-bar-is-opened/53509109#53509109

Answer (score 4):

Add the following to your `Activity`:

```
@Override public void onWindowFocusChanged(boolean hasFocus) {
    super.onWindowFocusChanged(hasFocus);
    // if hasFocus is false, notification panel is open.
}
```

Doco for this function is [here](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/Activity.html#onWindowFocusChanged(boolean)).

Comment: It's part right. A system dialog, like Power off & Restart dialog, can also make your window lose focus too.